# Check mark slightly misplaced

Tags: bug, badges, design

At https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges:

[image: pic]

At https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/nice-question:

[image: pic]

The little green check mark is slightly too high in the second image.

Please just lower it a bit.

---

Another instance of bug found on https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour:

[image: pic]

---

Produced on:

- Windows 8.1 Chrome V 47.0.2526.111 with default settings
- Mac OS X El Capitan Chrome V 47.0.2526.111 with default settings
- Mac OS X El Capitan Safari V 9.0.2 (11601.3.9) with default settings
- Win 7, Firefox 62.0

---

The issue is still here after a long time, I would like to hear if this is going to be fixed or not.

Comment: Reproed on Google Chrome, Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I don't understand how this question is considered "answered" when the only "answer" is more like a lengthy comment...

Comment: @Werner "*I don't understand how this question is considered 'answered' when the only 'answer' is more like a lengthy comment*" I never expected the green tick, and was arguably not 100% justified. So don't disagree with you there. It's removed now anyway. However, I don't see the reason for negativity towards my answer. I spent a fair bit of time testing this on other sites to check how widespread the issue was, viewed source code/CSS and checked image alignments to get further info, etc. I believe I gave *useful* feedback (as did 6 other users).

Comment: @James: Don't take things too personally here. My comment wasn't intended to cause you sleepless nights through negativity. I just consider an accepted answer as being the one that helped most... and in the case of a [meta-tag:bug], I would assume this is either a [meta-tag:status-completed] (or the like) answer, or a work-around. Your's is not this.

Comment: Issue is still there.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Oh!

Comment: @PatrickHofman I was about to post this, 5 years and 10 months later... :-|

Answer (score 8):

This bug isn't just on the "Nice Question" badge, it is on all badges.

And this bug is not just on MSE, it's also on SO, MSO, and Programmers, so I'm taking a guess it's like this on all sites.

The green tick next to the badges on the main badges page is vertically centered to the badge, whereas on *every* single badge page it's above vertical centre of the badge.

The main badge page uses a div class of "badge-cell-large", whereas the single badge page uses a div class of "single-badge-badge".
Both classes have different CSS styling.

It's possible one of the page's design was changed/updated and not the other.

Or it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - i.e. they wanted it slightly higher on single badge page, *because web designers*.